# Align elements without padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, css-tables

I am trying to achieve a perfectly aligned table using divs. So far this is what I have:

[image]

I'm looking to have the time section on the left side of the entire row, but the text right aligned to stop creating space differences like so:

[image]

I've tried using `text-align: right;` and `direction: rtl` and playing about with more divs but nothing seems to be working so far.

Relevant html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>EVENTS SCHEDULE</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>

        <div class="col-lg-8 date">
            <h4>Thursday, January 26th</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>

        <div class="col-lg-8 event">
            <span class="event-time"> 1:00 PM</span>

            <h5 class="event-title">Special Olympics Unified Snowboarding Final</h5>
            <dd>SLOPESTYLE</dd>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
    </div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.date {
    background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 1);
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.event {
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.event-time {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Arial", Arial, sans-serif;
    direction: rtl;
}

.event-title {
    text-align: left;
    line-height: .5em;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Arial", Arial, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 80px;
}

.event dd {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Verdana", Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding-left: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bootstrap classes, You may want to try lower classes for your alignment since the size of the screen you are displaying may not meet large.

replace col-lg-8 with col-sm- or col-md- so your html will look like

```
    <div class="col-md-8 date">
        <h4>Thursday, January 26th</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry. Looks like your issue is with the 80px Padding on the .event-title class. use a similar padding for both elements or remove the padding completely